# Vuetify 3 beta outline not rendering as desired

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I started to use vuetify 3 beta, I know it is not stable according to the documentation but I still tried.

`<v-text-field placeholder="Type a name" class="v-field__outlined" outlined></v-text-field>`

End result is the basic vuetify text field.

How do I fix this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The styles are no longer individual prop values.

Styling options are now set via a prop called `variant`

`variant="outlined"`

It is also no longer possible to mix the different styles and `rounded` appears to be missing so far.

https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#variant